# Number of courses completed by student..MOODLE

Tags: moodle

what would be query to find no.  of students who have completed their courses in MOODLE?
 i am using follwing query :

elect  mu.id as student_id,count(mcc.course) as completed_course from  mdl_user mu              join mdl_course_completions mcc on mcc.userid=mu.id JOIN mdl_course mc on mc.id=mcc.course WHERE mcc.userid = $user_id               group by mu.id

Answer (score 0):

I notice that you seem to have limited the results to only a single userid (WHERE mcc.userid = $user_id), so you should probably remove that restriction if you want to get details of more than one student.

You don't really need to join with the mdl_course or mdl_user tables, as there is only one mdl_course_completions table for each student + course combination.

You should, however, add a restriction on the 'timecompleted' field, to make sure it is not null (mdl_course_completions records are created when a student starts on a course, to record the timeenrolled and timestarted; when the course is complete the timecompleted field is set as well).

This should give you:

```
SELECT userid AS student_id, COUNT(*) AS completed_courses
FROM mdl_course_completions
WHERE timecompleted IS NOT NULL
```

Which will list the number courses each student has completed.

If, instead (and as stated at the start of the question), you want the number of students who have completed at least one course, then the query would be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(userid)
FROM mdl_course_completions
WHERE timecompleted IS NOT NULL
```